# How to add List's all values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

of course I can use `for() {}`
but is there any function which can add all values in array?
if do you know, please tell me.
thank you.

Comment: `var sum = myArray.Sum();` `using System.Linq`

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] b = new int[a.Length];
a.CopyTo(b, 0);

b.ToList().ForEach(c=>{
    System.Console.WriteLine(c);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;
```

then...

```
var array = new double[] { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };

var sum = array.Sum(value=>value);

Console.WriteLine($"Sum is {sum}");
```

[image]